# mysql join other table search

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

```
SELECT * FROM
companies as C
LEFT JOIN usersSearchCache as UC ON C.id = UC.objectId
WHERE UC.userId = ? AND C.keywords LIKE ?
```

So basically I have an table: usersSearchCache, that has an objectId, the objectId
is linked to the id of the companies table, I need to search where the keywords of the company are matching in the cache of the user.

The query above isn't working but I don't understand why.

Comment: Could you post the error and some code that you are using to execute this command? As well as the parameters you've provided.. and your expected results?

Comment: Are you getting an error, or no results?  Can you add a complete query with the ?'s replaced?

Comment: im getting no error or any result but im sure the parameters are right.

Comment: It'll help if you can post some code for us to see.. I'm not sure how else to help you except ask if you've tried to manually run the command with its parameters in mysql, and if those tables have any data that will meet your query's requirements?

Comment: If you reference the UC alias in your WHERE clause (like you are), then your LEFT JOIN actually acts as a regular JOIN.

Comment: Oke the situation is as following:

- We got users in a user table, all those users can visit pages of objects, when they visit these pages, a new records is created in the table userSearchCache.

Now what I got is a search field, where the users inserts the name of the object they want to search, so the current query is:

SELECT * FROM
companies as C
LEFT JOIN usersSearchCache as UC ON C.id = UC.objectId
WHERE UC.userId = ? AND C.keywords LIKE ?

But the problem is, it ain't searching anything, the parameters are 100% sure passed through and no error, just no

Comment: Have you tried a `RIGHT JOIN` instead? It seems that the record must first exist in the `usersSearchCache` table, from which you join out to `companies` based on the id and objectId, respectively... and then filter where the user is such and the keywords are like.. Now the next question is if the value being checked here: `C.keywords LIKE ?` exist(s) in `companies` and if there are no spaces in between or that the `escaped characters` you are passing are actually decoded in the keywords column..

Comment: You like statement is probably failing pending the variable ? you're passing.  like 'a' is sorta silly.  like 'a%' picks up all records that starts with a.  Check your 'like' wildcard usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got users in a user table, all those users can visit pages of objects, when they visit these pages, a new records is created in the table userSearchCache.

```
select * FROM userSearchCache UC
where UC.userId = ?
```

returns something like

```
userId,objectId
1,123
1,345
```

Now what I got is a search field, where the users inserts the name of the object they want to search, so the current query is:

```
JOIN companies C ON UC.object_id=C.id

userId,objectId,keywords
1,123,"yoga,savate,pilates"
1,345,"tennis,biking,soccer"
```

to find "biking", I would use LIKE '%BIKING%'

```
select * 
FROM userSearchCache UC
JOIN companies C ON UC.object_id=C.id
where UC.userId = ? AND c.keywords LIKE '%'+?+'%'
```

Does your keyword parameter already contain the wildcard characters '%'